# (python image-processing) Using equalize_hist()

Tags: python, image-processing, matplotlib, histogram

I'm doing image equalization.
I've learn that equalization is making bars to similar heights in histogram.
But when I equalize my img-data, it just changes img-data-values.
So the heights of histogram is same as before equalization.
What did I do wrong?

In Short, I want to make x-axis to (0 ~ 15) and get similar heights in histogram.(what I think equalization)

[my assignment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E1KWK.png)

[After equalization](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UBMCM.png)

full code

## making data

I made data with lots of full() and append()

(if someone knows better way to solve my assignment than plz tell me)

## reshaping and mixing data

```
 table = data.reshape((5, 149))
img2 = array(sorted(table, key = lambda k: random.random()))
```

## plot data

```
f = plt.figure()
f.show(plt.hist(img2.flatten(), bins = 256))
```

## equalize

```
img2_ex = ex.equalize_hist(img2)
```

## plot equalize data

```
f = plt.figure()
f.show(plt.hist(img2_ex.flatten(), bins = 256))
```

Comment: We do not know what you are doing. The best way to change that is to provide the code that produces the unwanted result, see [mcve].

Comment: thanks for advice, I edit my questions.